# How to show waves while record an audio using flutter sound

Tags: flutter, dart, audio

i am using `flutter_sound_lite` package to record users voices and i am trying to show the waves while user is recording but couldn't do that

i need something similar the following image

[image]

this is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sound_lite/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {


  FlutterSoundRecorder? record ;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    record!.closeAudioSession();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    record = FlutterSoundRecorder();
    record!.openAudioSession();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: IconButton(
          onPressed: (){
            record!.startRecorder(
              toFile: 'dooo_doo.aac'
            );
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.mic),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the flutter package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sinusoidals .

You can basically get data from your buffer and calculate sound intensity(this can be given in decibels). Then, Write your decibel value on top of the given parameters with some specific formula in the widget such as frequency, wave amount and so on using setstate(({ })). I did it and it looks quite satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this package https://pub.dev/packages/audio_waveforms
This plugin generates waveforms while recording audio in any file formats supported by given encoders or from audio files.

**Example:**
[image: Wave example]